# Daily timeseries forecasting, with weekly and annual cycle

Tags: r, forecasting

My aim is to forecast the daily number of registrations in two different channels.

Week seasonality is quite strong, especially the weekends and also observed annual effects. Moreover, I have a few special event days, which significantly differ from the others days.

First, I applied a TBATS model on these two channels.

```
x.msts <- msts(Channel1_reg,seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
# fit model
fit <- tbats(x.msts)
fit
plot(fit)
forecast_channel1 <- forecast(fit,h=30)
```

First channel:

```
TBATS(0, {2,3}, -, {<7,3>, <365.25,2>})

Call: tbats(y = x.msts)

Parameters
  Lambda: 0
  Alpha: 0.0001804516
  Gamma-1 Values: -1.517954e-05 1.004701e-05
  Gamma-2 Values: -3.059654e-06 -2.796211e-05
  AR coefficients: 0.249944 0.544593
  MA coefficients: 0.215696 -0.361379 -0.21082
```

Second channel:

```
BATS(0, {2,2}, 0.929, -)

Call: tbats(y = y.msts)

Parameters
  Lambda: 0
  Alpha: 0.1652762
  Beta: -0.008057904
  Damping Parameter: 0.928972
  AR coefficients: -0.586163 -0.676921
  MA coefficients: 0.924758 0.743675
```

If I forecast the second channel, I only get blank values instead of any forecasts.

1. Could you please help why is that so?
2. Do you have any suggestion how to build in the specific event days into this model?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

`tbats` and `bats` are occasionally unstable, and your second model is showing infinite forecasts. There are already some bug reports about similar issues.

In any case, as you want to use event information, you would be better building a harmonic regression model with ARMA errors.

For example, suppose your event information is recorded as a dummy variable `event1`. Then the model can be fitted as follows:

```
harmonics <- fourier(x.msts, K=c(2,2))
fit1 <- auto.arima(x.msts, lambda=0, 
   xreg=cbind(harmonics,event1), seasonal=FALSE)
f1 <- forecast(fit1, 
   xreg=cbind(fourierf(x.msts, K=c(2,2), h=200), rep(0,200)))
```

This assumes that the event will not occur in the next 200 days (hence the 200 0s). I have used harmonics of order 2 for both weeks and years. Adjust these to minimize the AICc of the model.

This model is actually very similar to the TBATS model you are fitting except that the `lambda` value has been specified rather than estimated, and the seasonality is fixed over time rather than being allowed to evolve. The advantage is that the harmonic regression model tends to be more stable, and allows covariates to be included.

Comment: I've read through many of your publications, and it's so nice to see that you are the one who is helping me, thank you Professor @RobHyndman!  :)

Following your recommendations, I have created a past events and future events in l_holidays and f_holidays. 

/* 
`harmonics <- fourier(x2.msts, K=c(3,2))
fit2_harm <- auto.arima(x2.msts, lambda=0, 
                        xreg=cbind(harmonics,l_holidays), seasonal=FALSE)
f2 <- forecast(fit2_harm, 
               xreg=cbind(fourierf(x2.msts, K=c(3,2), h=fcast_int), f_holidays))` */

Model performance and details:
http://tinyurl.com/zush5lm

Comment: what do you think about this model? Would it be beneficial to somehow identify outliers and treat them in a separate covariate just as events?